# Trying to tick all checkboxes on a page through the console

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using the below; because the page I'm using has disabled checkboxes, but I also think it might have hidden checkboxes that are getting selected

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").not(":disabled").prop("checked",true);
```

Is there a way I can use the console to show me if I have hidden checkboxes, and is the above code suitable, or should I also have something that is using `.not("display:none")` in there somewhere?

Comment: using this code you will get the hidden checkbox only , `$("input[type='checkbox']:hidden")`

Answer (score 2):

Hidden checkboxes can be found the same way as `:disabled`, via `:hidden`, giving you:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").not(":disabled").not(":hidden").prop("checked",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(index,element){
      if($(this).is(":hidden") == false) // Ignore hidden checkbox
      {
            $(this).prop("checked",true);
      }
    })
```